# Regex to match any currency in page

Tags: javascript, php, regex

Would like to take a string filled with text and extract the prices from it. For example, here's what it should match:

```
$1,234.55
$90.99
$90
$100.30
$203
```

Regex help here would be amazing, thank you so much for you time! This will be used in either PHP or Javascript.

Comment: Show your attempt to do this..

Comment: Where are we starting? What is the page/string structure? How much control do you have over the source? Is Regex the only option? YOu say any currency, do you also mean Euros, Peso etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the below regex to match all the price strings,

```
\$\d+(?:,\d+)*(?:\.\d+)?
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/oE0iR5/1)

**Explanation:**

- `\$` Matches the literal `$` symbol.
- `\d+` Matches one or more numbers.
- `(?:,\d+)*` Matches a comma and the following digits zero or more times.
- `(?:\.\d+)?` Matches a dot and the following digits. `?` turns the whole match as optional one.

Answer (score 0):

**Tada:**

`\$[\d,]+(?:\.\d+)?`

[Here it is in practice](http://rubular.com/r/I3j4wQJkUC)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one `/^\$(\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*)(?:\.(\d{1,2}))?$/`:

```
"$1,121,234.55".match(/^\$(\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*)(?:\.(\d{1,2}))?$/);
```

(JS code)

This should be work for following patterns:

```
$1
$2.21
$56,231
$12,212.12
$56,823,163.12
```

First group `$1` would be the full dollars (e.g. without cents) and second group `$2` would be cents.

Description in details:

- `\$` is dollar sign
- `(\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*)` captures whole dollar value

  - `\d{1,3}` it's the first three digits
  - `(?:,\d{3})*` everything which goes after first three digits
- `(?:\.(\d{1,2}))?` captures the cents, it's optional

  - `(?:\.` ignores the dot
  - `(\d{1,2})` and captures cents

Good luck!

Comment: Yeah, it's complex, but it would capture in strict format what you needed, e.g. this wouldn't capture `$1234,54,1.1231` but others would do.